# Reverse foreignkey relationship when using django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using the [django-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter) app to filter my 'Project' model. Here are my models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProjectAllocation(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Here is my filter:

```
class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = {'name': ['icontains'],
        }
```

I would like to include a 'location' field in my project filter. On reading django-filter's [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) , the only example they have is for a direct foreignkey relationship.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? If possible, please guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter

Answer (score 0):

Could not find the answer to this question surprisingly, so here it is:

```
fields = {'name': ['icontains'],
           'projectallocation_set': ['icontains']
          }
```

and the filter:

`projectallocation_set = django_filters.CharFilter(name='projectallocation_set__name')`

but I'd better use related_name for those 2 ForegnKey fields in ProjectAllocation model the same way.